# JavaScript string interpolation on strings assigned as property values in objects

Tags: javascript, string-interpolation

I have the following object:

```
var obj = {
   number: "123456789"
   tel: `The clients phone number is ${number}. Please call him!`
```

How can I insert the number value in the tel-string?

Comment: Declare and assign a value to `number` variable before declaring the `obj` variable.

Comment: ^^ That.  The properties don't exist until you terminate the object initialisation, so `number` does not yet exist as a variable.  Alternatively, don't add `tel` until afterwards... `obj.tel = \`The clients phone number is ${obj.number}. Please call him!\``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot access the object while is being initialized. You can either assign the property after the object initialization or you can define a *getter* property:

```js
const obj = {
  number: "123456789",
  get tel() {
    return `The clients phone number is ${this.number}. Please call him!`;
  }
};

console.log(obj.tel);
```

Comment: @Dalorzo: FWIW, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility says it's supported in Edge.